# Wrong HTTP code returned using MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0

Tags: vbscript

I could use some assistance with some vbscript code that's not working as expected. I'm cycling through a few web image urls to see if their valid and found a few that are returning incorrect HTTP return codes as follows.

```
'these urls return code 403 but they are valid image urls
url = "https://www.skymedia.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Sky-Sports-Mix.png"
'url = "https://www.skymedia.ie/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2016/01/channel-logo-tlc.png"

'this url returns code 403 which is correct
'url = "http://www.lyngsat-logo.com/hires/aa/astro_supersport_my.png"

'this url returns code 200 which is correct
'url = "http://cdn.cablefax.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/golf-logo.jpg"

Set req = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
req.open "GET", url, False
req.send

'check http status codes
If req.Status = 200 Then httpCode = "HTTP 200 OK - "
If req.Status = 400 Then httpCode = "HTTP 400 Bad Request - "
If req.Status = 403 Then httpCode = "HTTP 403 Forbidden - "
If req.Status = 404 Then httpCode = "HTTP 404 Not Found - "

WScript.Echo httpCode & url
```

Any help solving this mystery is greatly appreciated.
-Al

Comment: *"I could use some assistance with some vbscript code that's not working as expected."* it could be helpful to tell what happens and how that differs from your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Some web servers may refuse to respond to some clients like MSXML.
The `User-Agent` header is used to identify, ServerXMLHTTP's default is something like `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)`.

Instead, try to set a known User-Agent, Mozilla Firefox for example.
Also, you can use [statusText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763774(v=vs.85).aspx) to simplify your code.

```
Set req = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
req.open "GET", url, False
req.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0"
req.send
httpCode = "HTTP " & req.Status & " " & req.StatusText

WScript.Echo httpCode
```

Comment: Thanks. I gave that a try but all urls now return code 200.

Comment: @A.Udell I have got `403` for `http://www.lyngsat-logo.com/hires/aa/astro_supersport_my.png` and `200` for the others like you expect.

Comment: Sorry, should have explained better. I get 403 for this url for example but I can view it fine in my browsers (IE, Edge) - https://www.skymedia.ie/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2016/01/channel-logo-tlc.png

Comment: @A.Udell Did you set a known user-agent like I suggest? I did and have a 200 OK response with the script. https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Qit.png

Comment: Yes, I set the user-agent as you suggested and got code 200 for all 4 urls.

Comment: I've tried 3 user-agents with mixed results.  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko", and 
"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)"

Comment: @A.Udell I couldn't follow the issue. Update the question with your final code and the example URLs so let's think again.

Answer (score -3):

Ok, this user-agent appears to have solved my issue:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1)
```

Comment: Instead of leaving another answer up-vote and approve [Kul-Tigin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42401128/692942) as it answered the question.