# The script works well when I use MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0, but it fails miserably when I switch to MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP.6.0

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, serverxmlhttp

I've created a script in VBA to scrape breadcrumbs from a [webpage](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FQT4LX2) using XML HTTP requests. The script works well when I implement the ActiveX component `MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0`, but it fails miserably when I switch to `MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP.6.0`.

As I've got a plan to use proxies within the script, it is necessary that I stick with `MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP.6.0`. However, the seond script doesn't work. To let you know, when I print the `.responseText`, I see gibberish content within it, as in the following:

`??GN?!v:h??_??Og<]?????X ?6??'o??F??6 ?uh????x?r???????sP??????????[B??k????]??????yC????'???L???????,*?Z?????   ?vX ?c?q\t?j??????K?|???P 7??k?y?<;?>????a?*P1????w???[?T?/f?? ?7?gn??V<E?Z??6t:??1??????E'v?1?? ?w??+??????-aD????wy?`.

Using `MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0` (works flawlessly):

```
Option Explicit
Sub GrabInfo()
    Const Url$ = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00FQT4LX2?th=1"
    Dim oHttp As Object, Html As HTMLDocument, breadCrumbs$

    Set Html = New HTMLDocument
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

    With oHttp
        .Open "GET", Url, True
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        MsgBox "Status code: " & .Status
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        breadCrumbs = Html.querySelector("#wayfinding-breadcrumbs_feature_div")
        MsgBox breadCrumbs
    End With
End Sub
```

Using `MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP.6.0` (throwing an error showing `Object Variable or With block variable not set`):

```
Option Explicit
Sub GrabInfo()
    Const Url$ = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00FQT4LX2?th=1"
    Dim oHttp As Object, Html As HTMLDocument, breadCrumbs$

    Set Html = New HTMLDocument
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP.6.0")

    With oHttp
        .Open "GET", Url, True
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        MsgBox "Status code: " & .Status
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        breadCrumbs = Html.querySelector("#wayfinding-breadcrumbs_feature_div")
        MsgBox breadCrumbs
    End With
End Sub
```

> > How can I make the second script built on `MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP.6.0` work?

Comment: [Proxy issue MSXML2.ServerXmlHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026800/excel-vba-msxml2-xmlhttp-6-0-vs-msxml2-serverxmlhttp-6-0?) ?

Comment: It is not a proxy issue. Instead, I gave a reason why I wish to stick with MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP.6.0.

Comment: [Differences between XMLHTTP and ServerXMLHTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605613/differences-between-xmlhttp-and-serverxmlhttp) The return value of `<ServerXMLHTTP object>.responseText` is not a literal html strings. `querySelector` can't find the element. You can check the conten after saving it as a local text file.

Comment: I've already looked into the response text to find the desired element, but there is nothing but unintelligible stuff. However, If you replace the existing URL with [this](https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=pizza&geo_location_terms=San+Francisco%2C+CA) and the selector with `.result h2 > a.business-name`, you can see that the script is able to find the element accordingly. So, it's not always the case that querySelector can find the element in the response text returned by ServerXMLHTTP @taller.

Comment: Agree. I guess it depends on how the remote server responds to requests from `ServerXMLHTTP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and got the same "glibberish" response. However, removing the statement `setRequestHeader` (where you set the user agent) solved that issue and the response was readable, while using a different User agent (the one suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42401128/7599798)) resulted in the strange response.

Note that the result of `Html.querySelector` is an object, not a string and you should use

```
Dim breadCrumbs as Object        
Set breadCrumbs = Html.querySelector("#wayfinding-breadcrumbs_feature_div")
MsgBox breadCrumbs.innerHTML
```